# Mathematica: NMinimize not working as expected

Tags: optimization, wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to make a pipe network optimization program using the useful NMinimize function.

I'm testing my program with a tiny network: 3 pipes and 16 different diameters. There are 16^3 = 4096 combinations for this pipe network, and using brute force I found that the best feasible combination (cheapest) is the one with diameters {8,4,7} and its value (given by an objective function that I defined) is:

```
ObjectiveFunction[{8,4,7}]
(* 1.61503*10^6 *)
```

My ObjectiveFunction is a little big. I don't think I'm going to post it. I've used _?NumericQ, _?ListQ and such to define ObjectiveFunction and all the other functions that I'm using.

Then I applied NMinimize to the ObjectiveFunction (with constraints, etc) to solve the problem and this is what I got:

```
(* {1.83824*10^6,{d1 -> 8, d2 -> 4, d3 -> 8}} *)
```

At first I was like "Yeah, ok, that's pretty close". But then I verified the solution and...

```
ObjectiveFunction[{8,4,8}]
(* 1.84853*10^7 *)
```

... Wut?

Then I tried this, using ReplaceAll:

```
ObjectiveFunction[{d1,d2,d3}]/.{d1 -> 8, d2 -> 4, d3 -> 8}
(* 1.83824*10^6 *)
```

Same result as NMinimize.

So there is a problem with `ReplaceAll` and `NMinimize`. They don't give the expected result.

Why? What should I do?

Comment: This feels like you have defined an ObjectiveFunction that takes symbolic args and a different one for numeric. Be sure to ClearAll[ObjectiveFunction] when you are working on the argument patterns.